# What causes a compiler error while doing a bitwise &?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a char pointer pointing to a char:

```
char *a = 'A';
```

And while doing a bitwise `&`:

```
*a & 0x11
```

I am getting a compilation error. What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 5):

`a` is a variable pointing to the character at memory location 65. Operating systems usually do not allow access to such addresses and give you a segmention violation.

If you declare `a` not as a pointer, then it works.

```
char a = 'A';
char b = a & 0x11;
printf ("%x %x\n", a, b);
```

Still, the result depends on the signedness of `char` and the used character set.

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrectly storing a character (`'A'`, single quotes) into a pointer to char. You can fix this by storing a pointer to a string (`"A"`, double quotes) though in this case, you will also need to add `const` since those strings are constants.

```
 const char *a = "A";
 char v = (*a) & 0x11;
```

Answer (score -1):

The way it's done is

```
char i='A';
char *a = i;
```

or

```
char i='A';
char *a;
a=&i
```

Pointer can only store the address.

Comment: Looks like you're missing an `&`.

Comment: I think i could not prase my question properly. I write it this way. I want to do bitwise on char a= A with 0x11. Its giving compile error.
 (a & 0x11)